# Linux Mint 15 unable to install on VM VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Appears that something maybe up with my VM set-up as it wouldn't install Fedora either.

Problem will be I load up the VM and hit F12 to boot from the CD/DVD which is pointed to the mounted ISO file which will at this attempt is linuxmint-15-cinnamon-dvd-64bit.iso 
At which point I will see a screen saying Linux Mint Autoboot in 10.. 9.. then as soon as the count down reaches zero I am stuck on this screen.

[Desktop Caption http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/51/xd93.png](http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/51/xd93.png)

Full Size image: [a link](http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/51/xd93.png)!

I have 3D Acceleration Enabled and gave 128mb Vid Mem. So unsure what else I could try. I assigned 4096Mb of RAM ... The image shows 2048 but I have since changed that to 4GB.

Anything I could try or troubleshoot? Most results online show issues relating to post installation or during installation, yet I cannot begin the installation.

-

As instructed the ISO is MD5 Verified with a checksum and when using a prepared VDI it still fails to hit the OS. I have the options to select Linux Mint.. Linux Mint +Rec ect. But soon as I choose one it hangs on a black console screen with an underscore.

Comment: Is your host system 64-bit?  What happens if you do not hit F12 during VM boot?  Your boot order should select the ISO with no key hits.

Comment: My host system is Windows 8.1 Pro 64 Bit, without hitting F12 it runs the mounted drive as the order is Floppy, DVD, Hard Disk.
Same thing happens though. It just hangs.

Comment: Has the ISO been verified (MD5, etc.)?  If you download a prepared VDI with a linux machine, does that run properly?

Comment: I can't read the screenshot, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Additionally, I'm familiar only with VMWare Player, not VirtualBox. But can't you just mount the ISO in the vm software and boot/install from it?  I don't understand why you need to press f12 at any point.

Comment: Not sure how to verify the ISO. Currently downloading a prepared VDI with LinuxMint machine in there an will let you know how it goes when installed.

Poldie - the ISO is mounted as said in my original post pressing F12 to boot from disk or letting it it auto run to disk (the mounted ISO) produces the same results.

Comment: Wherever you download ISOs, there is usually an MD5, SHA1, SHA256, etc., file with checksums.  Sometimes the checksums are found on the download webpage.  On your local system, you can regenerate the checksum to verify the integrity of the file.

Comment: Right I see.. Just checked the website and can see there is an MD5 and also used winMd5Sum and the same result appeared. So I am assuming by that it means it's verified.

Comment: When trying a prepared VDI it sticks to the loading screen where I'm staring at command line screen with just the white underscore.

Comment: Latest version of Virtualbox is a good idea.  Also try adding 'nomodeset' (with no quotes) to end of linux line in grub on boot.

Answer (score 12):

Let me end this.

- enable PAE/NX in settings/system/processor.

Comment: +1 - I had the exact same problem as the OP (with Linux Mint 16), and this solved it.

Comment: It took me ages of tweaking, but I finally got past this hurdle, such a simple click can solve so much...

Answer (score 3):

When creating the new VM, do not select linux 2.6/3.x. Select Ubuntu. I had the same problem and solved by selecting ubuntu.

Comment: I had the same problem and resolution with Mint 17.2 and Virtualbox 5.0.10

Comment: funnily this one solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Which version of VirtualBox do you use? Is it 4.3? Do you see Ubuntu (64 bit) in your drop-down menu "Version"? I see you chose **linux 2.6/3.x**. Will it work if you choose **linux 2.6/3.x (64 bit)**?

If you do not see the 64 bit versions, you may be affected by [this bug](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=57871) in VirtualBox 4.3. The solution is to downgrade VB to 4.2, (and upgrade to 4.3 afterwards if you like). Then you will see 64 bit version.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your computer BIOS and look for a setting that reads something like "Secure Virtual Machine Mode" or "Virtual Machine" and change the setting to "Enable".

Answer (score 0):

Disable Hyper-V from Windows Features On/Off. Then restart your computer and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is AMD combi ATI Radeon

- Start Linux in Virtualbox
- Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> key  before booting
- Append to boot script: `setparams load_video insmod gzio`
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

Result: no black screen or other rubish, linux starts in rendering mode and be able to install